# Categorize df based on column orders

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have to Sort the columns in the order C, D, E, B, A  and categorize them in ascending order.

Where as -

- Ds with False and Es with True should have highest priority after column C
- Column Max(B) and Max(A) should have next priority after C, D, and E
- Finally, C and B with zeros should have lowest priority.(should have, D and E ordered after Max (A)

`df`:

```
        A   B   C      D      E
    0   8   5   0  False   True
    1  45  35   0   True  False
    2  35  10   1  False   True
    3  40   5   2   True  False
    4  12  10   5  False  False
    5  18  15  13  False   True
    6  25  15   5   True  False
    7  35  10  11  False   True
    8  95  50   0  False  False
```

Conditions to Sort as per the below column order:

**Example Condition order:**

```
Max(C), D, E, Max(B) and Max(A) where as C!= 0  and B!=0
Also Column D with `True` and E with `False` should be on the top 

C, D, E, A, Max(B), and Max (A) where as C== 0 and B !=0
Also Column Ds with `True` and Es with `False` on the top 

C, D, E, A, B, and Max(A) where as C== 0 and B ==0
Also Column Ds with `True` and Es with `False` on the top
```

Example categorization Order -

```
 Category 1 -  C, D(True), E(False), B, A and C!=0
 Category 2 -  C, D(True), E(True), B, A and C!=0
 Category 3 -  C, D(False), E(False), B, A and C!=0
 Category 4 -  C, D(False), E(True), B, A and C!=0
```

Then consider C=0

```
 Category 5 -  B, D(True), E(False), B, A and B!=0 and C=0
 Category 6 -  B, D(True), E(True), B, A and B!=0 and C=0
 Category 7 -  B, D(False), E(False), B, A and B!=0 and C=0
 Category 8 -  B, D(False), E(True), B, A and B!=0 and C=0
```

and so on

I tried, by updating ascending orders but not getting expected output:

```
df.sort_values(['C', 'D','E', 'B', 'A'], ascending=[False, False, False, False, False]) # without category
```

Here is the expected output: -

```
   A   B   C      D      E       Category
6  25  15   5   True  False       1    
3  40   5   2   True  False       1
4  12  10   5  False  False       3
5  18  15  13  False   True       4
7  35  10  11  False   True       4
2  35  10   1  False   True       4
1  45  35   0   True  False       5
8  95  50   0  False  False       6
0   8   5   0  False   True       7
```

Comment: Is output correct? `Category 1 -  C, D(False), E(True), B, A and C!=0` in output is `6  25  15   5   True  False       1` - not swapped `D=True, E=False` ?

Comment: @jezrael - Thanks for correcting, no its not correct. Let me correct

Comment: @jezrael - Update the question, please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) for set new conditions by `C,D,E` columns, so then sorting by `Category, A, B` columns with default ascending order:

```
#test not equal 0
m0 = df['C'].ne(0) 

#chained True & False
m1 = df['D'] & ~df['E']
#chained True & True 
m2 = df['D'] & df['E']
#chained False & False
m3 = ~df['D'] & ~df['E']
#chained False & True
m4 = ~df['D'] & df['E']

df['Category'] = np.select([m0 & m1, m0 & m2, m0 & m3, m0 & m4,
                            ~m0 & m1, ~m0 & m2, ~m0 & m3, ~m0 & m4], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])

df = df.sort_values(['Category','A','B']) 
print (df)
    A   B   C      D      E  Category
6  25  15   5   True  False         1
3  40   5   2   True  False         1
4  12  10   5  False  False         3
5  18  15  13  False   True         4
2  35  10   1  False   True         4
7  35  10  11  False   True         4
1  45  35   0   True  False         5
8  95  50   0  False  False         7
0   8   5   0  False   True         8
```

Comment: @jezrel - Thank you for quick answer. A quick question, I have 1000s of such rows, in which case category number  would increase such as 8, 9, 10.. (max up to 14 I guess ) as the pattern would differ when there would be zeros in A, B and C and the combination of D and E would also matter there.  How can I update `np.select` in that case.

Comment: @jezrel - probably  I will have to create the range for `m0 | m1`,` m0 |m2` ...~m0 | m1`... etc. Correct?

Comment: @Laxmikant - Not sure if understand, there are also tested `A,B` for `0` ?

Comment: yeah, absolutely...A and B also have checked for  0. But the first priority should be for C, B and then A

Comment: @Laxmikant - Is possible explain more? e.g what is output of `np.random.seed(2020)
N = 30
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.randint(5, size=N),
  'B':np.random.randint(4, size=N),
 'C':np.random.randint(3, size=N), 'D':np.random.choice([True, False], p=(0.5,0.5),size=N), 'E':np.random.choice([True, False], p=(0.5,0.5),size=N)})` ?

Comment: Sorry, could not reply to you, had got tied up with production issues later. But I figured out the rest of the solution. Thank you very much for your help.